# Airflow Clear automatically triggering tasks?

Tags: airflow

I am running `airflow clear -t task_regex -s 2019-02-23 -e 2019-02-24 dag_id` to clear and then re-run a task. However, Airflow is automatically queuing up this task to run, instead of waiting for me to run `airflow backfill`. Is this a setting I can change? Also, it looks like it queued only some of them to run, and not others. In other words, immediately after clearing the task, half the dates had a green box and the other half had a white box.

Comment: I'm not sure if you found the solution yet, I encounter the same issue that once I remove the run history, and that will trigger the task run immediately.

Answer (score 1):

- I believe setting [`catchup_by_default`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L471) is meant for this very purpose and should be set to `False` in order to achieve what you want

  > Command Line Backfills still work, but the scheduler will not do
  >   scheduler catchup if this is False,
- But then you need not configure it *globally* since it can be modified on **per-`DAG` basis** too using [`catchup` parameter](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3309)

  > however it can be set on a per DAG basis in the DAG definition
  >   (catchup)

Comment: My catchup is set to False, yet the task is automatically rerun every time I clear it